# Gate way URL for eBay API

Tags: api, http, ebay-api

Help me clarify terminology regarding the HTTP API.
Gateway URL and endpoints are the same thing, correct?
This is just the place to make a GET or POST call, correct?

Now for my question.  It seams for each of the eBay API has its own gateway.
The Shopping API gate way is http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?

### I'm assuming the fallowing:

Finding: http://open.api.ebay.com/finding?

merchandising: http://open.api.ebay.com/merchandising?

... and so on.

Is this correct? or am I misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the end point is the gateway. Each API has its own endpoint/gateway url. You would think that eBay would name their endpoints with the schema you provided, but they didn't. You will need to click on "Making a Call" after selecting the API you want the endpoint for in the documentation.

***Example:***

[image]

Here is the endpoint documentation for the [Trading API](http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/XML/docs/Concepts/MakingACall.html#ServiceEndpoints), [Shopping API](http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/shopping/docs/Concepts/ShoppingAPI_FormatOverview.html), and [Finding API](http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/finding/Concepts/MakingACall.html#callstruct).

Also you should know that not every endpoint is going to require the same info. For the trading API you are going to need a Token from the seller as well as your APP ID, whereas the shopping and trading API only needs the APP ID.

Comment: Thank you.  I've been fighting with the eBay API documentations and there sorry excuse for "hello world tutorials".